# Codeigniter framework : List with a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
stdClass Object
(
    [enq_id] => 10008
    [enq_userid] => 3
    [enq_catid] => 43
    [enq_attachid] => 8
    [enq_name] => werwer
    [enq_desc] => werwerwerewr
    [enq_end_date] => 22/08/2016
    [enq_budget] => 1212
    [enq_quantity] => 1212
    [enq_city] => Alpy
    [enq_feedback_rate] => 0
    [enq_activity_id] => {"165":"Restaurants and coffee shops","215":"studio - proffesional license"}
    [enq_imgid] => 0
    [enq_date_added] => 2016-08-08 22:47:19
    [enq_date_modified] => 2016-08-08 22:47:26
    [enq_status] => 1
    [enq_url] => werwer-10008
    [enq_unique_id] => 0
    [subenquries] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [subenq_id] => 33
                [enq_id] => 10008
                [subenq_name] => wqeqweqwqwe
                [subenq_desc] => qweqweqweqweq
                [subenq_cat_id] => 44
                [subenq_budget] => 12312
                [subenq_quantity] => 1234
                [subenq_date_added] => 2016-08-08 22:47:19
                [subenq_date_modified] => 2016-08-08 22:47:26
                [subenq_status] => 1
            )

    )
```

)

This is my result. I want to list it with looping. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, Alex. Please check out [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: You can loop over a stdClass with a normal foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( $your_array AS $key_array => $val_array ) 

{

 echo $key_array.":".$val_array;

 if( isset($val_array[0]) && is_array($val_array[0]) )

 {

  foreach( $val_array[0] AS $key_inner_array => $val_inner_array ) 

  {

   echo $key_inner_array.":".$val_inner_array;

  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Welcome @Alex George

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to resolve your code

```
foreach($resultobject as $result){ 
//to resolve outer object
echo $result->enq_id;
//to resolve inner object
$innerobject=$result->subenquries[0];
echo $innerobject->subenq_id
}
```